# Not able to get custom login form

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I started learning spring security 6 and i configured the security class, but i'm not able to access the custom login form, getting blank page but when i remove authorizeHttpRequests i'm able to access the custom login form

- spring boot version - 3
- spring security version - 6.2

```java
package com.nikhil.springBoot.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyWebSecurityClass {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf(c -> c.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .formLogin(login -> login
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password"))
            .logout((logout) ->   logout.invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success"));
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

**login.jsp**

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        ${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message }
        <div class="form">
            <form class="form" action="login" method="POST" >
                <h2>Login Form</h2>

                <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" required />

                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" required />

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Controller class**

```java
package com.nikhil.springBoot.controller;

import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import com.nikhil.springBoot.dto.UserDTO;
import com.nikhil.springBoot.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView home(ModelAndView mav) {
        mav.addObject("message", "Welcome Aliens");
        mav.setViewName("welcome");
        return mav;
    }

    @GetMapping("registration")
    public ModelAndView registerPage(ModelAndView mav, UserDTO userDto, @ModelAttribute("message") String message) {
        mav.addObject("user", userDto);
        mav.addObject("message", message);
        mav.setViewName("register");
        return mav;
    }

    @PostMapping("registerUser")
    public ModelAndView saveUser(ModelAndView mav, @ModelAttribute UserDTO user, RedirectAttributes redirectAttribute) {
        userService.saveUser(user);
        redirectAttribute.addFlashAttribute("message", "User registered successfully...");
        mav.setViewName("redirect:/registration");
        return mav;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/logout-success")
    public String logout() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try updating `authorizeHttpRequests` to `authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request.requestMatchers("/login").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())`?

Comment: tried...but no luck